# How to get RSSI value from Wifi on different device?

Tags: java, android, positioning, android-wifi, rssi

> Hello, i have new project about indoor positioning. After detect users and get ip address and mac from device who connect in Router, so i'm confused how to get rssi value on that users. Is possible right? Somebody pls help me :) this is my thesis, thankyouu

I used android studio btw.. This is my code to display ip address, mac, and SSID device who connect to wifi

```
private class HostsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Void> {
    public HostsAdapter(Context ctxt) {
        super(ctxt, R.layout.list_host, R.id.list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_host, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.host = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            holder.mac = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mac);
            holder.vendor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vendor);
            holder.logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final HostBean host = hosts.get(position);
        if (host.deviceType == HostBean.TYPE_GATEWAY) {
            holder.logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.router);
        } else if (host.isAlive == 1 || !host.hardwareAddress.equals(NetInfo.NOMAC)) {
            holder.logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.computer);
        } else {
            holder.logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.computer);
        }
        if (host.hostname != null && !host.hostname.equals(host.ipAddress) && !host.hostname.equals(host.rssi)) {
            holder.host.setText(host.hostname + " (" + host.ipAddress + ")");
        } else {
            holder.host.setText(host.ipAddress);
        }
        if (!host.hardwareAddress.equals(NetInfo.NOMAC)) {
            holder.mac.setText(host.hardwareAddress);
            if(host.nicVendor != null){
                holder.vendor.setText(host.nicVendor);
            } else {
                holder.vendor.setText(R.string.info_unknown);
            }
            holder.mac.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.vendor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.mac.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.vendor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"How to get RSSI value from Wifi on different device?"_ The other device needs to read its own RSSI and somehow send it to your app. It could for example share it via a [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). That of course means that the device would need be running an app from you. So, you can't "spy" another device's RSSI (and then the indoor location) but other devices can report the necessary data themselves.

Comment: ya i see, oke sir, thx for your help :)